# UIImageView should be as circle view instead of diamond in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I have UICollectionView with UIImageView on it (as shown at image).

[image]

And I want to make it as circle view. But, when I running application, it's appearing as diamond (image below).

[image]

In `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`
 I setup it as

```
[cell.photo setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    cell.photo.layer.cornerRadius = cell.photo.bounds.size.width / 2;
    cell.photo.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    cell.photo.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

For setup image I used libs [SDWebImage](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage)

And **I'm sure, that cornerRadius value is correct** (it's half of image width). Also I didn't make any manual changes in storyboard properties (position set as auto layout).
What I missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that cell can be re-layout after `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and size of cell will be changed after it.

Solutions for you:
1) Put `cell.photo.layer.cornerRadius = cell.photo.bounds.size.width / 2;` into

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

2) Create custom class for your `UICollectionCell` and override `layoutSubviews` function:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.photo.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Adding '(void)layoutSubviews' into custom UICollectionCell working like a magic. Thank you.

Comment: layoutSubviews will do for me.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me a lot.

In Subclass of UICollectionViewCell, CustomCell.m:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self layoutCell];
}

-(void)layoutCell
{
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    [[imgThumbView layer] setCornerRadius:imgThumbView.bounds.size.width/2];

    [[imgThumbView layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor];

    [[imgThumbView layer] setBorderWidth:1.5f];

    [[imgThumbView layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your image view a circle you have to make sure that your frame is a perfect square and set corner radius to more or less 60.
This works for me hope this help you!

Comment: what about if I have biggest image? in my case I have 170x170 size, so radius is 85

Comment: My mistake, you are right for me the solution was in view didWillAppear add the code     self.imageview.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageview.bounds.size.width/2;
    [self.imageview.layer setMasksToBounds:YES]; And make sure that in xib the imageview clipsubviews checkbox is marked. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, yeah, this works in UITableView, but not in UICollectionView :(

Answer (score 0):

Your cornerRadius value is correct but `cell.photo.layer.masksToBounds = NO;`which in incorrect set it to `cell.photo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;` and if its still not working then make sure that the height and the width of your `ImageView` should be same.